# LoadLibraryEx ignoring fully-quallified path name?

Tags: windows, dll

From my reading of the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684179.aspx), I would think (in the case where a dll of that base name is *not already loaded*) that passing a fully-qualified absolute file name to `LoadLibraryExW` would look at that path only.

E.g. (and note that this is the correct CSIDL_SYSTEM path, if that makes a difference)

```
LoadLibraryExW (L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\foobar.dll", LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE);
```

should fail if that file does not exist in that location.  But I'm getting funny results that make me think it's taking the base name and applying it to the `PATH`, on Windows 8.1. and finding a file with the same name somewhere else.

Furthermore, if I use `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE` it prevents me from finding out just where it actually found it.

What does this function *really* do in this respect, and does it vary with OS version?

(BTW, I know about `LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_SYSTEM32`, but that does not exist on all OS versions.  I want to run on anything as far back as XP.)

It's especially confusing since I thought that using the absolute path was an effective fix for a previous time I saw it finding improper files via PATH, as a portable alternative to `LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_SYSTEM32`. So maybe it varies by OS or some other magic changes the behavior.

Comment: You'll need to show the code and provide a test case with full details. In particular, mind the applicable `LOAD_` flags mentioned in the documenation you linked.

Comment: You can use Process Monitor (available from the MS web site) to confirm whether or not the file really is being loaded from somewhere else.  One thought: you remembered to use backslashes in the path, not forward slashes, right?

Comment: The one case where I think a fully specified DLL path will come from another actual location is when Wow64 redirection is involved.  If your application is a 32-bit app running on a Win64 OS, by default file access to System32 will be redirected to SysWow64. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187.aspx   Perhaps that is what's happening to you? Change the path to something other than System32 and I think you'll see that the LoadLibraryEx() function fails.

Comment: I was reminded that having an "app-name.exe.local" file or directory in the same directory as the application causes all DLLs load to look in that directory first.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682600.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I have observed using [Process Monitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_Monitor) that a fully-qualified file name used as the argument for `LoadLibraryEx` will indeed cause **only that path to be checked** (that is, when it does need to load a file because there's no DLL by that name already loaded). This was observed for a 32-bit process.

In the case of the System32 directory, what was given as an argument as C:\Windows\System32 appears in ProcMon as C:\Windows\SysWOW64, on a 64-bit OS.

This was observed in

- Windows XP SP3, 32-bit (oddity: if the DLL was not present, QueryOpen is called twice with the same path)
- Windows 7, 32-bit
- Windows 10, 64-bit

One caveat is that even if named DLL is loaded from the specified directory with an absolute path, its dependent DLLs are loaded with normal searching of the PATH.  This is not an issue when `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE` is used.

Answer (score 1):

Windows will ignore the path if there's already a DLL of that name loaded.

So if there's a `foobar.dll` already loaded in the process from some other path, then, even though you specified a full, absolute path to a different `foobar.dll`, it will just return a handle to the first one and bump the reference count.

**Edited:** Found the [documentation for this behavior](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx):

> If a DLL with the same module name is already loaded in memory, the system checks only for redirection and a manifest before resolving to the loaded DLL, no matter which directory it is in. The system does not search for the DLL.

Comment: Sorry, the dll in question is not already loaded (with that observed behavior). I know that's the case for referencing an existing loaded file. I'll clarify the question.

Comment: Perhaps you could edit the question to show all the "module loaded" messages from the output window in the debugger.  That should show us exactly what's going on (including whether or not another DLL of the same name is loaded).